# Find the shortest path between the lines

Tags: java, libgdx, path-finding

I'm working on a project with the library LibGDX version 1.6.4

Now I need to find the shortest path between two points, but this path must be drawn between lines that intersect. Like this:

[image]

The left side of the image I have my lines. Initially I have the original path, with point A, point B and all internal points. But I need to project this path so that it is proportional. As shown in Projection #1 and #2. (the picture is only a draft).

After project the path, of course the lines are overlapped, for the path between point A and B is shorter.

**Now comes my question**, I need to calculate the shortest path within this projection. Equal to the green path displayed on the right side of the image.

I found the [Pathfinding API](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Pathfinding-API) of LibGDX, but did not understand how it could help me in this case.

If I was not clear, please let me know.

Comment: like you're already doing in your scribbles you should first find the intersection points of your line segments and create new nodes that can be used for your path finder too. Then you could easly apply A* on the segments

Comment: I see the A*. But the problem is that these overlapping points can pass through 3 or 4 lines. Like [this](http://postimg.org/image/xyg8zr8zp/). The intersection I got with [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html). But I did not understand as A* work in my case.  Do you know any example of implementation?

Comment: @DouglasJunior Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, Postimage.com stop working :( ... Try this http://imgur.com/a1cNp6s